# Centering Scrolling Text

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
                <div id="square" class="zoomInUp animated"> <p class="header-name">Theo Bearman</p> 
            <p class="header-title">Interests in <span class="rw-words rw-words-1">
                    <span>Web Designer</span>
                    <span>Web Developer</span>
                    <span>Graphic Designer</span>
                </span></p></div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
/* Animated words ------------------------------------------------- */

.rw-words{
text-indent: 10px;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 100;
text-align: center
}
.rw-words-1 span{
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-animation: rotateWord 9s linear infinite 0s;
-ms-animation: rotateWord 9s linear infinite 0s;
animation: rotateWord 9s linear infinite 0s;
text-align: center
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(2) { 
-webkit-animation-delay: 3s; 
-ms-animation-delay: 3s; 
animation-delay: 3s; 
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(3) { 
-webkit-animation-delay: 6s; 
-ms-animation-delay: 6s; 
animation-delay: 6s; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateWord {
0% { opacity: 0; }
2% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px); }
5% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);}
25% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
40% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(30px); }
80% { opacity: 0; }
100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes rotateWord {
0% { opacity: 0; }
2% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(-30px); }
5% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px);}
25% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
40% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(30px); }
80% { opacity: 0; }
100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes rotateWord {
0% { opacity: 0; }
2% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px); transform:        translateY(-30px); }
5% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); transform: translateY(0px);}
25% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); transform: translateY(0px); }
40% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(30px); transform: translateY(30px); }
80% { opacity: 0; }
100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
.rw-sentence { font-size: 18px; }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px){
.rw-sentence { font-size: 9px; }
}
```

---

```
.header-name2 {
background-color: #000;
padding: 5px 17px;
display: inline-block;
color: #fff;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: 400;
text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
border-left: 3px solid #f00;
border-right: 3px solid #0045ff;
}
.header-title {
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 100;

}
```

What would I need to do to change my code so that header-title is centered underneath header-name2 with the scrolling words included?

A live example is [here](http://theobearman.com/cv/). You can see that the text "Interests in" is centered but the scrolling words are not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is recommended that you create a reduced example instead of linking to an external site, because that makes your question susceptible to link rot, making it irrelevant to future users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
.rw-words{
  ....
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.rw-words-1 span{
  left:25%;
  right: 25%;
}
```

and remove text-indent from `.rw-words`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but all that does is put the words on a new line and they are still not centered. I want the scrolling words and `header-title` centered with `header-name2`

Comment: But for me everything is ok !

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You could give `.header-title {   margin-left: -110px; }`

Comment: That's got me half there but the different words that are scrolling are not being centered under `header-name2` because some of the words are longer than others. Click the live link above again to see what I mean. **Note: You will have to reload the CSS**

Comment: @nevermind I have put the code for it above. On the link it is the black box with my name in it.

Comment: Alright I see what you mean. Think about this, if the words are different sizes, would we want the "Interests In" title compensating to handle the center alignment by jumping a couple of pixels left and right? Maybe instead we could left align "Interests In" with your name block above so that it doesn't move. What are your thoughts, maybe a margin-left:-90px could look better?

Comment: We could also try adding a fixed width to the revolving spans to make the alignment work - `.rw-words-1 span {  text-align: center; width: 100px; }`

Comment: @RepeatQuotations That didn't work. Just put them on top of eachother. I've accepted the answer above. The only downside of it is they scrooling words have to be on a new line. If you have a solution which allows me to keep the 'Interest in' text and the scrolling words on the same line that would be awesome!

Comment: Oops! Yeah you can just add `width:100px;` to `.rw-words-1` to visualise what I was talking about, we still want the other styles in that class. You can play with `text-align` on the class too to achieve a different look. Good luck!

Comment: @RepeatQuotations I've given it a go [here](http://theobearman.com/cvtest/). What do you think compared to [this](https://theobearman.com/cv/)?

Comment: I think the second option provided by @Hamid looks sweet as. If you could align them on one line nicely using a negative margin on `.header-title` and a fixed width on `.rw-words-1` that would work too. Either way, it's a good looking site!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74515/discussion-between-theo-bearman-and-repeatquotations).

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="rw-words rw-words-1">
                <div id = 'cont'></div>
                <div>Web Designer</div>
                <div>Web Developer</div>
                <div>Graphic Designer</div>
            </div>
```

Put a blank container div in there

```
#cont {
     position:relative;
     width: 10em;
}
```

Problem is absolute position is not taking up any "space"
and therefore not computed in centering.